# Delphi Aero просвечивает текст

Tags: aeroglass, delphi

Здравствуйте! На днях начал играться с разными эффектами в `Delphi`, и наткнулся на такую проблему при использовании `Aero Glass` (у меня установлен `Delphi 2010`): когда на поле, затрагиваемом `glass`, расположена кнопка, или любой другой элемент, какая-то его часть просвечивается. Не знаю, почему так получается, но я пробовал же на нескольких компьютерах. И на всех одно и тоже.

Скриншот:

[image: img]

Моя программа: http://rghost.ru/45288872

Comment: В замешательстве. Давно не запускал дельфи, да и пишу с тетриса... Но попробуйте поиграться с опаком: `XXX.ControlStyle := XXX.ControlStyle + [csOpaque];`

Answer (score 2):

`doublebuff:=true` на форме